# How to edit file in Docker base image before build a new image from it

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image using a base image of my previous project. Dockerfile of it as follows,

```
FROM saji/base-project:latest
COPY Libs/*.jar /home/base-proj/lib/
```

But before build this image, I want to change the configuration file which has inside the **saji/base-project:latest** base image file path of `/home/base-proj/conf/config.xml`

Can I know how to do it with Docker daemon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the file in your local system, just replace the file during build time.

```
FROM saji/base-project:latest
COPY Libs/*.jar /home/base-proj/lib/
COPY config.xml /home/base-proj/conf/config.xml
```

This will overide the base image file config.xml file.

If you do not have the `config.xml` then copy it from the base image and then use the above dockerfile.

```
docker run -it --name base_container --rm saji/base-project:latest
#then copy the file
docker cp base_container:/home/base-proj/conf/config.xml  ./
```

Or if you just want to change at run time then ( I assume you have config.xml file)

```
docker run --name my_container -it --rm -v $PWD/config.xml:/home/base-proj/conf/config.xml your_image_name
```